# Doctrine ManyToMany with referencedColumnName

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two models that have a Many to Many relationship. The ID is not managed by doctrine and is instead managed by a GUID generator from a different app. So my entities have a field called `uniqueIdentifier` and not `id`. So doing:

```php
class Bar {
    /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo", mappedBy="bar")
    */
    private $foo;

}

class Foo {
    /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
    */
    private $bar;

}
```

I get an error stating that `Column name 'id' referenced for relation from App\Entity\Foo towards App\Entity\Bar does not exist`. Which I know is due to the doctrine default of mapping stuff to `_id` for the reference column name and `table1_table2` for join tables.

I can't override the default because a few models do have auto generated values and rely on the `id` field. Instead, I would like to do something like the following:

```php
class Bar {
    /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo", mappedBy="bar")
    * @JoinColumn(name="foo_uid", referencedColumnName="uniqueIdentifier")
    */
    private $foo;

}

class Foo {
    /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
    * @JoinColumn(name="bar_uid", referencedColumnName="uniqueIdentifier")
    */
    private $bar;

}
```

This does not work and I get the same error. How to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your association mapping should be something like this:

```
class Bar
{
    /**
     * @var Foo[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bar")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="table1_table2",
     *     joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_uid", referencedColumnName="uniqueIdentifier")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bar_uid", referencedColumnName="uniqueIdentifier")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    private $foo;
}

class Foo {
    /**
     * @var Bar[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo")
     */
    private $bar;
}
```

Remember `foo_uid` and `bar_uid` columns will be in `table1_table2` table and `uniqueIdentifier` is identifier on Foo's and Bar's tables.